# inheriting from list and other object

Tags: python

I have a class A defining basics behaviour of my object and a class B inheriting from list and C inheriting from str

```
class A(object):
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

class B(list, A):
  def __init__(self, inputs, a):
    A.__init__(self, a)
    return list.__init__(self, [inputs])

class C(str, A):
  def __new__(self, input, a):
    return str.__new__(self, input)
  def __init__(self, inputs, a):
    A.__init__(self, a)

def __init__(self, input, a):
    A.__init__(self, a)
```

What I'd like is that the user build object B or C which behaves like a list or a str, those classes just have metadata usefull for our application but not for the user ... using class B is easy, if I want to change the values, I can clear it or append new values ... but how can I modify the value of a C object. I checked **setattr** but this one required an attribute name ...

thanks,
Jerome

Comment: Can you clarify what "how can I modify the value of a C object" means?

Comment: Why is class C not calling the `__init__` for A (as B does).

Comment: Strings are immutable, so it would not make sense.

Comment: @Tom Dalton: yes it actually does, I changed the example code

Comment: There is a lack of good reasons *ever* to inherit `list` or `str`, let alone as part of a system like this.

Maybe you can share the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: @Mike Graham: I have classe A=Parameter and classe B=ParameterList. The developer define a set of this 2 classes within a Workflow class and a process function that uses the variables previously defined (ex: self.input is defined and can be used in the process function ...). To make think easy for the developer, I don't want him to specify the attribute when using the parameter (self.input.value) but directly the attribute ... am I clear enough ?

Comment: I'm not positive I understand. I'm not suggesting you have a confusing interface--I'm merely suggesting that you don't inherit from these classes, as doing so is error-prone. What you will provide, then, is the interface you WANT, not some buggy interface you didn't even realize you were providing.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def __init__(self, a):
...     self.a = a
... 
>>> class B(list, A):
...   def __init__(self, inputs, a):
...     A.__init__(self, a)
...     return list.__init__(self, [inputs])
... 
>>> class C(str, A):
...   def __new__(self, input, a):
...     return str.__new__(self, input)
...   def __init__(self, inputs, a):
...     A.__init__(self, a)
... 
>>> c = C('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>>> c = C('foo', 1)
>>> c
'foo'
>>> c.a
1
>>> c.a = 2
>>> c.a
2
>>>
```

You can change the metadata on a `C` instance. Like `str`, you can't change the value of the characters it contains.

If you want a mutable string, you're going to have to create that in pure python. However, given that everyone else gets by without that, consider whether you can use the built in facilities, such as `TextStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Strings are immutable - you cannot change their value once created. Lists are mutable, which is why you can change their value (contents) after creation.

Comment: yes, this is what I was thinking! Thanks! The only solution I have is to do something like this: c = C("test", 55) then c = C("test2", **c.__dict__) what will only change the value, is that clean ?

Comment: This confuses the immutability of strings with the inability to set properties on them.

Comment: I don't think so - the OP is asking for how to set the 'value' of a string.